# Scope of Hurwitz's Theorem for Diophantine approximation

Tags: irrational-numbers, diophantine-approximation

Hurwitz's Theorem states that for any irrational $\zeta$ there are infinitely many pairs of integers $p,q$ such that
$$
|\zeta - p/q|<\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}q^2}.
$$
A good Diophantine approximation $p/q$ to the number $\zeta$ satisfies
$$
|\zeta - p/q| < |\zeta - p'/q'|
$$
for all $q'<q$.

My question is, do all good Diophantine approximations satisfy the relation in Hurwitz's theorem?

I have looked at the cases I know how to calculate, examples where $\zeta$ is a quadratic integer, and it seems that they do. And based on the intuition these numbers are notably badly approximable, and that other number are generically *more* rational (that is they have rational approximations for which $|\zeta - p/q|$ falls faster than $q^{-2}$) one would expect that generic good Diophantine approximations satisfy the inequality in Hurwitz's theorem. However this is just hand waving.

The answer to this may be widely known but I wasn't able to find it clear statement.

Comment: You should have tried the notoriously worst of them, the Golden Ratio $\varphi=(1+\sqrt{5})/2$. $3/2$ is a good Diophantine approximation, but $2^2\sqrt{5}|\varphi-3/2|>1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hurwitz' theorem states that if $\frac{p_{n-1}}{q_{n-1}},\frac{p_n}{q_n},\frac{p_{n+1}}{q_{n+1}}$ are three consecutive convergents of the continued fraction of $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^+\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, at least one of them fulfills $\left|\alpha-\frac{p}{q}\right|\leq \frac{1}{q^2\sqrt{5}}$, but that is not granted to hold for *any* convergent, and it is pretty simple to construct counter-examples to such a claim, as Professor Vector points out in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it known if there exists a constant $c$ such that $|\alpha-p/q|\leq c q^{-2}$ for all irrational numbers?

Comment: @ComptonScattering: you question lacks some quantifiers. For any constant $c\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$ and any $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^+\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, there are an infinite number of rational approximations $p/q$ such that $|\alpha-p/q|\leq c q^{-2}$. Such constant is optimal in the following sense: for any $c<\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$ you may construct an irrational number $\alpha$ such that all the convergents of $\alpha$ fulfill $|\alpha-p/q|> c q^{-2}$.

Comment: On the other hand, the inequality $|\alpha-p/q|\leq q^{-2}$ ($c=1$) holds for all the convergents of $\alpha$.

Comment: Yes sorry I meant for all convergents of all irrational numbers. Which I understand you to have answered in the affirmative for $c=1$ in the second comment. Thank you!